# Is it legal to record a video browsing a website and commenting on that?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I'd like to make a Youtube video, in which I make comments browsing a website. This would be for educational content. Can I do that without asking permission?

(I'm from Hungary, Europe.)

Answer (score 1):

Hungarian [Act No. LXXVI of 1999 on Copyright](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=444836) (with revisions in 2001, 2007) allows certain uses as "free use", as described in Ch. 4 of the act. Free use is possible "only so far as it does not conflict with a normal exploitation of the work and does not unreasonably prejudice the legitimate interests of the author, and it is in compliance with the requirements of fairness and is not designed for a purpose incompatible with the intention of free use".

There is a bit of a puzzle that, according to the law (English translation), "The provisions relating to free use shall not be interpreted in an *extensive manner*", which seems to correspond in the [Hungarian text](https://net.jogtar.hu/jr/gen/hjegy_doc.cgi?docid=99900076.TV) to
"kiterjesztően értelmezni", which I suppose means "broadly interpreted": that is, "school education" means precisely school education, and not general information-dissemination.

One of the permitted cases of free use is 34(1):

> From a work any part may be cited by indication of the source and
>   naming the author indicated therein. Such citation shall be true to
>   the original and its scope shall be justified by the nature and
>   purpose of the borrowing work.

The meaning of "citation" in this translation is unclear, insofar as the term usually means something like a bibliographic description (author, date, title) whereby something is attributed to an author. The Hungarian text says

> A mű részletét - az átvevő mű jellege és célja által indokolt
>   terjedelemben és az eredetihez híven - a forrás, valamint az ott
>   megjelölt szerző megnevezésével bárki idézheti.

which I don't understand (it seems to have to do with the meaning of *idéz*). The issue here is whether this allows actual copying of the protected work, or only allows summarization (paraphrasing) of the content along with a bibliographic citation (as one finds in academic articles). (2) then says

> Part of a literary or musical work or such a type of an entire work of
>   a minor volume disclosed to the public may be *borrowed* for the
>   purposes of illustration *for teaching and scientific research*, with
>   the indication of the source and the author named therein, to the
>   extent justified by the purpose on condition that the borrowing work
>   *is not used for commercial purposes*.. Borrowing shall mean the use of a work in another work to an extent that goes beyond citation.

The question is whether the law gives such free use to "teaching and scientific research", or does it specifically mean "school education". The Hungarian texts says

> E fejezet rendelkezéseinek alkalmazása szempontjából *az iskolai
>   oktatás* célját szolgálja a felhasználás, ha az az óvodai nevelésben,
>   az általános iskolai, középfokú iskolai oktatásban, az alapfokú
>   művészeti iskolai oktatásban vagy a felsőoktatásról szóló törvény
>   hatálya alá tartozó felsőfokú oktatásban a tantervnek, illetve a
>   képzési követelményeknek megfelelően valósul meg

The same (italicized) expression is used in Art 33(4) which says

> For purposes of the provisions of this chapter the use shall be taken
>   to serve the purposes of school education if it is implemented in
>   accordance with the requirements of education and with the curricula
>   respectively used in kindergarten, primary school, secondary school,
>   industrial school, vocational school education, the primary education
>   of arts, as well as in higher education falling under the scope of the
>   law on higher education.

which supports the interpretation "school education". While under US law we tend to understand any form of "providing information" to be "education", the Hungarian law appears to be specifically about classroom use.

Sect. 35(1) permits kinds of "private use" copying, which this would not be. There are numerous other rather specific permissions such as allowing performances in school for educational purposes *and* a statement that a dancing party at a school is not included. Given the extreme specificity of the law, since there is no category that covers "posting a video of a web page", we have to conclude that it is allowed under the category "free use" (which then means that permission is required). [Law CVIII](http://www.hipo.gov.hu/sites/default/files/2001_cviii_torveny.pdf) might initially seem to be relevant, but appears to be limited to information services and "public service"; there is no other obviously applicable law that I can find.

In other words, you would need to consult with a Hungarian copyright attorney to get a professionally-informed answer. It appears that such a use would not be allowed: I emphasize the word "appear".

This also assumes that the content of the web page is actually intelligibly visible to the viewer.